# NavigationItem on [UISplitViewController`s master ViewController] is disappear on iPad(iOS 9 / 10)

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

- This is part of storyboard
  [image: storyboard]
- MasterViewController presented by another view controller
- on iPad iOS 12 : left & right bar button item displays fine
  [image: screen on ipad]
- BUT! on iPad iOS 9/10 : left & right bar button item disappears after viewDidAppear()
  [image]
- on Debugger, tableview`s navigation item is exsists

> po (((self.parent as? NoteMasterViewController)?.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first as? NoteTableViewController)?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
>
> ▿ Optional
>     - some :

What is going on Here? :(

Comment: Is this a production project? I'm interested to check it out, let me know if you can provide a sample project for this.

Comment: @Glenn I`m sorry. this is production project :( It is hard to reproduce error in new project :(

Comment: Okay, are you sure that you're adding the bar button close through storyboard and not by code?

Comment: @Glenn Yes. I tried same thing by storyboard, code and both. but nothing works :(
Buttons appears until viewDidAppear(), and I have no idea when buttons disappear....

Comment: A late reply. Just wanna confirm some more things before I post an answer. Can you post the code you've tried for adding the navbar button?

Comment: @Glenn Thanks for you help~! :) here is my codes for adding navbar button self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ios_btn_close"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.closeAction(sender:))) self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "범위 선택", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.selectBooks(sender:)

Comment: This is supposedly easy to solve, especially if you can give us a sample project with same issue to check out. I actually made a sample project to help you out on this, but I couldn't reproduce the bug. I hope someone could help you. But let me know if you have time to create a new sample project for this.